# When I run the npm install gulp-sass I get this error?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install, gulp-sass

I get this error after running the command **npm install gulp-sass**  I spend a lot of time to fix this bug but haven't succeeded. If anyone have an idea how to resolve this let me know.
Thank you so much.

I working on the personal project now I can't do anymore because I want to fix this first let me know what should I do.

```
 npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Ramish Hassan Riaz\\Desktop\\website-components\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.11.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ramish Hassan Riaz\\Desktop\\website-components\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\Desktop\website-components\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.11.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ramish Hassan Riaz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-18T07_14_06_749Z-debug.log`enter code here`
```

Comment: If you pay close attention to your error message, it's stated there that it tries to find python2, but you only have python 3.9 in your PATH. I'd suggest looking up the required Python version for this `gulp-sass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it, it's work for me!

1-

```js
$ npm uninstall gulp gulp-sass
```

2- run this code

```js
$ npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

3- reinstall gulp gulp-sass

```js
$ npm install gulp gulp-sass
```